# cups ignores -o raw option when printing using lpr to remote printer

Tags: zebra-printers, cups

Cups 1.6.3 printer setup on the network on computer #1.
Zebra Label Printer using Zebra EPL2 driver
*device for labelq: usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%20ZD420-203dpi%20ZPL?serial=D2J175123456*

On computer #2 cups autodetects:
When I run lpstat -t it says:
 *device for labelq: implicitclass:labelq*

When I execute " lpr -P labelq  **-oraw** rawprintercommands.txt," cups rasterizes the file and converts it to a pdf.  Therefore instead of getting a nice label, I get printercode on the label.

1) Why will cups not print in raw mode when I call the following?

lpr -P labelq  **-oraw** rawprintercommands.txt

I tried explicitly adding the printer on computer #2 as a raw printer and that works, but the whole auto setup with implicit class, I also expect to work when I use the -o raw option.  I need this to work in over 1000 sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try `lp -d labelq -o raw rawprintercommands.txt`